# APK size is increased due to audience-network.dex file

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-install-apk, facebook-audience-network

[image: Apk Analyzer Screenshot]

In Build.gradle file i m using follwing implemenation

```
 //facebook


 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:5.15.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0' // Required Dependency by Audience Network SDK
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+'
```

and also this for mediation google to facebook ads

```
  implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.26.1.0'
```

How to decrease the size of apk?

and How to remove the audience_network.dex from asset folder

Answer (score 2):

According to [sdk Change Log](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/changelog-android):

> SDK 5.3.0 - Apr 15, 2019
>
> The SDK is now bundled differently to improve our security measures.
>   We ship a separate asset that is a dex file with more code. Bytecode
>   manipulation of this dex file is not allowed.

This probably means that `audience_network.dex` should stay in the `assets` folder.